# Assigning value of data- attribute to seperate html element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have been trying to build a popup menu using HTML, CSS, jQuery. I obviously don't want to have to copy blocks of code for every menu item and am using (this) with the `data-*` attribute to do so.
My relevant code is:

```js
$(".source_dropdown_button").click(function() {

  var src_content = $(this).data("content");
  $(src_content).style.display = "block";

});
```

```html
<p><button class="source_dropdown_button" id="ds_dropdown_button" data-content="#ds_dropdown_content">Sources: Domestic</button></p>

<div class="source_dropdown_content" id="ds_dropdown_content">

  <a href="">External/internal link 1</a>
  <a href="">External/internal link 2</a>
  <a href="">External/internal link 3</a>

</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When I run it like this the console says that it can't assign *'display'* to  *undefined* so I replaced the lasts line with - `console.log(src_content)`

The console now returns the string `"#ds_dropdown_content"` which is the value I gave the *data-* attribute in my HTML while actually trying to assign the DIV with `id="ds_dropdown_content"` to the attribute value.

So I'm pretty sure I found my problem, I'm just short on solutions and haven't been able to find a successful answer on the internet.

Can someone please tell me: **how I can assign the contents of this element to the value of my data- attribute?** Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `$(src_content)` is a jQuery object, and it does not expose the `.style` property like JS does for HTMLElement.

Use jQuery's .css() Method:

```
$(src_content).css({display: "block"});
```

or extract first the Element using `[0]` or jQuery's `.get(0)` before using JS's `.style`

```
$(src_content)[0].style.display = "block";
```

- https://api.jquery.com/css/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style
- Also always use `type="button"` for `<button>`. Otherwise one day you'll start to submit forms ;)

---

A better suggestion would be to handle the styles exclusively via CSS stylesheet,
and use JS's `Element.classList.toggle()` or jQuery's `$().toggleClass()` to toggle that one specific class:

```js
$("[data-content]").on("click", function() {
  $(this.dataset.content).toggleClass("is-hidden");
});
```

```css
/* bool helpers */
.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button
     type="button"
     class="source_dropdown_button"
     id="ds_dropdown_button"
     data-content="#ds_dropdown_content">Sources: Domestic</button>
</p>
<div class="is-hidden" id="ds_dropdown_content">
  <a href="">External/internal link 1</a>
  <a href="">External/internal link 2</a>
  <a href="">External/internal link 3</a>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```